# asp mvc action needs to accept parameter with full stop in the name`

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, query-string, action

Not sure if this is possible but I need my action to bind to a query string parameter with a full stop in the name. Is this possible?

For example my query string is

```
http://foo.com?foo.bar=test
```

so is there anything I can put in my method declaration so I can pick it up?

```
public JsonResult TestAction(string foo.bar)
```

(I know this wont work)

I know I can get the value from the `Request` object but I'd rather not do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Bind attribute:

```
public JsonResult TestAction([Bind(Prefix="foo.bar")]string foobar)
```

Comment: thanks, just found it as you answered but the points are yours :D

Comment: You could also leave you method params empty then read the query string using HttpContext.Current.Request["foo.bar"]